# are multiple descriptions in product schema type a bad thing

Tags: seo, schema.org, structured-data

I noticed a website used the product schema type to mark up their product and used more than 1 description.

Is this a bad thing?
Are there any benefits from this?

Comment: First mistake of Schema is believing it will help your SEO. It helps Google and users understand your content easier. Quality content is understandable with or without Schema. The reason I brought this up was I noticed that you tagged the question with the SEO tag. However review stars will help indirectly assuming your products have them. Using multiple descriptions isn't going to help in anyway.

Comment: I know structured data does not have a direct impact with SEO but for many features it can have an indirect affect like a video thumbnail or image and like you stated, the stars for product pages.
With the descriptions, I was not sure if this would have any affect on SEO regarding the search engines not knowing which description to read.
I assume it will read all of them and take them all into consideration but was not sure.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think will have any impact. In fact, if they state two descriptions without using an array, then I believe that Google will only read the final description (if you test it the structured data testing tool, it will only highlight the final description stated), so I don't think there is much point.At least that is the case for the JSON-LD format.